# Java Android The value of the variable doesn't update

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I use the debugger to find that the value of townHallLvl stays 1 at the end

Please help

```
int townHallLvl = 1;


public void addTownHall(View v){
        if (townHallLvl == 11) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You can't have more than Town Hall lvl 11!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        add(townHallLvl);
        TextView townHallText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.town_hall_lvl);
        townHallText.setText(String.valueOf(townHallLvl));
    }




public int add(int lvl){
            int ans = lvl + 1;
            return ans;
    }
```

Comment: Change `add(townHallLvl);` to `townHallLvl=add(townHallLvl);` or in `add` method use `townHallLvl ` instead of `ans`

Comment: Your `add` function returns the value, but you don't update the `townHallLvl` yourself

Comment: Thanks guys!!! Helped so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
townHallLvl = add(townHallLvl);
```

You probably missed to assign back the value to townHallLvl.